# How can I use validations in Rails 3.1 to enforce composite uniqueness?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Customer model that belongs_to Brand. Customer has only name and identifier (a string) as attributes. I want to enforce the uniqueness of name and identifier only within a particular brand. How can I enforce that scoped uniqueness?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `:scope` parameter of the **[`ActiveRecord::Validations#validates_uniqueness_of` validation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of)**:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :brand_id, :scope => [:name, :identifier]
```

Alternately:

```
validates :brand_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:name, :identifer]}
```

Either way, this says, "for a given `name` and `identifier`, the `brand_id` must be unique".